# Selecting duplicates records except one in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, select-by-attribute, duplication

I'd like to know how to select duplicates records except one, with the "Select by attribute".

I've attached a picture to explain better the output needed.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In QGIS you can use ["Select by expression"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#select-by-expression) with this expression:

```
array_contains(
    array_remove_at(
        array_agg($id, "field"),
        0),
    $id)
```

It will select all duplicates except for the first one. This is done by creating an array of all feature ids, grouped by the field value. Then the first value of each group will be removed. Finally each remaining item will be compared to the `$id` of each feature. If it is inside the array, it gets selected, otherwise not.

[image]

Comment: It works! thanks a lot!